# Can't render multiple Background Image on specific attribute

Tags: html, css

Here in this css file I used "background image url" in body and then used another "background image url" in another class named ***container***. But here in `.container` class I'm facing problem with height attribute. If I use a definite parameter in height like `height:500px;` then my both two background image (body and container class) is being rendered perfectly.

```
body{
  background: url('../images/body-bg.gif') 50% 0;
  font:12px/18px arial;
  color: #717171;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.container{
    background: url('../images/main-bg.jpg'); 
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

But If I use `height:80%/100%..etc` or use `min-height:80%/100%..etc` then only my `body` background image is shown on the display. In this type of stage how can I solve my problem.

```
.container{
        background-image: url('../images/main-bg.jpg'); 
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
    }
```

or-

```
.container{
        background-image: url('../images/main-bg.jpg'); 
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

**Note: Basically I was doing this code from a video and in that video both two images rendered perfectly. And here are no issue with syntax or destination path.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't set height of a div in percentage without a valid positioning. Either assign it a position or use height in `vh` instead of `%`.

Do note that `vh` will give you the height of viewport but `%` will give the height of parent.

If you're assigning absolute position, don't forget to apply relative positioning to it's parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get your concept.
But I can't understand that I exactly do the same as the project I am doing from a video. There works perfectly but I can't. Even I run the whole code in my browser and I got a perfect result. But when I run the code snippet i faced the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're telling you container to have height 100% but compared to what? To make relative units work for height the parent needs to have a height defined.

You can use `flex-grow` as a workaround.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get your concept.
But I can't understand that I exactly do the same as the project I am doing from a video. There works perfectly but I can't. Even I run the whole code in my browser and I got a perfect result. But when I run the code snippet i faced the problem above.